# Unable to boot Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS ISO on VMware vSphere 4.1

Tags: vmware-vsphere, ubuntu-14.04

I have a VMware vSphere 4.1 server hosting several VMs. There is a legacy reason why we need to run this version.

When I create a new 64-bit Ubuntu VM and mount the 64-bit Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS ISO, the VM is unable to boot from the image. I know there's nothing wrong with the image because it works fine in VMware Fusion on my laptop. If I mount an older Ubuntu ISO (e.g., 8.04), the VM immediately boots from the image.

I suspect perhaps Ubuntu requires EFI firmware and vSphere 4.1 does not support EFI.  Can anyone confirm this, and if so, is it at all possible to run an Ubuntu 14.04 LTS VM on vSphere 4.1, perhaps by creating it elsewhere and migrating it to vSphere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, EFI support was first introduced with hardware version 9 in vSphere 5.1. Unfortunately, vSphere 4.1 only supports up to hardware version 7, so it seems that it's not possible to run an Ubuntu 14.04 VM on vSphere 4.1.